# Fast conversion from YCbCr to RGB, or, why is AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer so fast?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-video

Okay, I've been dealing with this for a couple of days, and I can't figure it out for the life of me.

So, I've got a CVPixelBuffer for each frame of my incoming video stream. That's fine. I encapsulate it in a CMSampleBuffer, all good, very fast. I enqueue it on an AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer, it's super quick, using <4% CPU.

But I can't do much with that. It's in YCbCr 4:2:2, and I need to work with RGB24. So, I looked around at the various conversion tools bundled with the system - CoreImage, Accelerate, VideoToolbox - and *nothing is as fast*. Not even close. The fastest I got was `VTPixelTransferSession` which actually uses a private Accelerate function under the covers, and it's *still* really slow. Just copying the buffer from the original 422 to a new RGB buffer uses about 15% CPU on my top-of-the-line iMac.

The thing I don't get is: surely, in order to be rendered on screen, this pixel buffer must be converted from YCbCr to RGB. It has to be. And yet, somehow, this conversion is magicked away from the CPU, performed presumably by the GPU, in a way that I can't figure out how to access.